# Return type based on the enum parameter

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I have a function e.g.

```
type DataType = 'json' | 'txt';
interface MyType {}

const getItem = <T extends string | MyType>(type: DateaType): T => axios.get<T>('...');

const r1: MyType = getItem('json');
const r2: string = getItem('txt');
```

Is there an option to apply conditional types to make the return type as strict as it is shown in the example?

Comment: You can use a conditional in the return type like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOAVc0C8UDkArAzgewDtMoAfLYAD2EwG4BYAKAEtDgIAnAMzgGNoAsiBSQoAbwC+TJgBMIvADZwO0LgFdCvYMyJQA5hGABJdgFsAPEigRqEQjNywEyVAD4AFKEgAuKEgCUvlY27PaOAER4ROFQAPxQQiLQvrjAHKx6tFDSjLxEqVAcAIxQGAbGZu44BMT+DLn5wIUATKX6hiYQplVUNHVAA)

Comment: thank you. need to improve my TS knowledge